# How can one invoke a keyboard shortcut from within an AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I need to invoke a keyboard shortcut from within an AppleScript code, e.g. Cmd+Ctrl+Opt+E.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Sure it works. System events can perform keystrokes. However, keystrokes are always sent to the frontmost application so to perform a shortcut for an application you must tell that app to activate first and then perform the shortcut. For example, I can open a new tab in Safari using command-t. That applescript would look like this...

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using command down
end tell
```

Now suppose you have a global keyboard shortcut. Global meaning it works from any application. Then you don't even need to activate an application first, just perform the keystroke. To press the keys you requested do this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "e" using {command down, option down, control down}
end tell
```

Comment: How would you use 'enter' in the keystroke? 'return' nor 'enter' doesn't work.

Comment: Normally you would just use... keystroke return. If that doesn't work you could try the key code for the return or enter key. I do not know the codes but if the code was 13 for example it's as simple as ... key code 13. If that doesn't work then you'd have to try user interface (ui) scripting. With ui scripting you can press and click on things so maybe you can click on that button. UI scripting is too complicated to explain here but you could google to find how to do that. Remember though, make sure the application is frontmost before trying any of these suggestions.

Comment: I tried using keystroke "return" and all it did was type out 'return' in the text entry window.

Comment: For example how would I do ctrl+shift+tab (moving back one tab in Safari)?  'keystroke "tab" using {ctrl down, shift down}' seems to have an issue here.

Comment: You'll notice I do not have quotes around the word return in my command. Try that. Same with tab... no quotes. Quotes is used when you want to type the letters in the quotes. You do not want that. Applescript will know the word return, tab and a bunch of other key words.

Comment: Right. Thanks! (I used the keycode in the end but it's good to know).

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke the keystroke, or if GUI Scripting is on, you can select a menu item from a menu.

Here's a great link explaining this in detail.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060921045743404

Answer (score 2):

depending on what you wish the keyboard shortcut to be you would use key stroke events for example

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "e" using {command down, option down, control down}
end tell

replace the "e" from after key stroke with what word or words you wish to input and then change the   {command down, option down, control down} to which keys you wish to be activated at the same time.

thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
activate application "Safari"

delay 3
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using {command down}
    delay 2
    keystroke "www.google.com"
    key code 36
end tell
```